# Select Laravel Collective não seleciona valor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collective

Estou tentando recuperar o valor setado no banco e ele ficar selecionado no form de edição. O valor 2 está chegando até o form mas não estou conseguindo que fique selecionado.

```
{!! Form::label('cupUnic', 'Único?') !!}
{!! Form::select('cupUnic', ['' => 'Selecione', '1' => 'Sim', '2' => 'Não'], 'null', ['class'=>'form-control', 'parsley-trigger'=>'change', 'required'=>'required']) !!}
```

Comment: Não bastaria colocar o 2 (valor do banco) onde está `null` na definição do `select`?

Comment: Se colocar 2 ele fica "Não" mas não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar a verificação para que se for 1 fique selecionado 1 senão selecione o 2.

Comment: E como está chegando o valor do banco de dados? Está em alguma variável? Ela só pode valor 1 ou 2, ou pode não possuir valor também?

Comment: O valor 2 esta chegando na variável $coupon->cupUnic Ela só vai ter o valor 1 ou 2 (Sim e Não)

Comment: Então se no lugar de `null` você colocar a variável, `Sim` ficará selecionado de a variável for 1 e `Não` ficará se a variável for 2. Não foi isso que você fez?

Comment: Eu tenho um campo chamado Valor único que aceita duas escolhas Sim (1) e Não (2), o usuário seleciona uma opção (Não por exemplo) mas ao ir para o formulário de edição eu quero que retorne a opção que o usuário escolheu, no caso "Não", mas ele está me retornando null. Quero fazer uma verificação para preencher com o valor que está vindo do banco.

Comment: Que confuso. Quem está retornando `null`? O valor que vem do banco de dados? Na pergunta você disse que o "2" estaria devidamente chegando até o formulário, então acredito que não seja, mas um campo do tipo `select` não possui valor `null`. Está bem difícil de entender seu problema.

Comment: Esse é um form para cadastrar e editar, no caso o valor está null pq o usuário vai escolher o valor, após escolher  e ir para o form de edição tem q vir do banco a opção q ele setou.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58620/discussion-between-marcelo-and-anderson-carlos-woss).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como discutido no [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58620/discussion-between-marcelo-and-anderson-carlos-woss), você estará utilizando o mesmo formulário tanto na página de cadastro quanto na página de edição. Na página de cadastro, você deseja que o terceiro parâmetro de `Form::select` seja `null`, pois o usuário ainda não selecionou algum valor. Já na página de edição, você deseja que este terceiro parâmetro seja o valor de `$coupon->cupUnic`, que é o valor armazenado no banco de dados. Considerando que está utilizando PHP 7, como dito também no chat, você pode utilizar o operador de coalescência nula para retornar o valor da variável, se esta estiver definida, ou `null` caso contrário.

```
$coupon->cupUnic ?? null
```

No seu caso, o `Form::select` ficaria:

```
{!! Form::select('cupUnic', ['' => 'Selecione', '1' => 'Sim', '2' => 'Não'], $coupon->cupUnic ?? null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'parsley-trigger'=>'change', 'required'=>'required']) !!}
```